# In Emacs, how can I load a certain file when (require 'x) is called?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) for [eassist](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EAssist) (*eassist-list-methods* is quite handy). In eassist.el there's the line

```
(require 'semantic)
```

which fails if CEDET isn't loaded.  The thing is that I don't need CEDET all the time and it takes a long time to load so I want to defer loading it until I call *eassist-list-methods*.

Is there a way to run

```
(load "cedet")
```

when *semantic* (or something else that is provided by CEDET) is *required*?

I'm looking for a simple solution that doesn't change eassist.el.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genehack is probably right; I'm being too literal in answering the question.  The best way to handle something like this is to figure out which function(s) are required by external code, and add `autoload`s for them.

But if `autoload` won't work in your case, the normal way to do something when a file is loaded is to do

```
(eval-after-load "semantic" '(load "cedet"))
```

But I just noticed that you say that semantic.el fails to load if CEDET hasn't been loaded first.  As implied by the name, `eval-after-load` runs the code *after* the specified file is loaded.

You can try finding a different file to trigger loading, instead of using semantic.el.  (Perhaps some other file that semantic.el requires.)

If necessary, you could hook into `require`:

```
(defadvice require (before CEDET-require activate)
  (if (eq 'semantic (ad-get-arg 0))
      (load "cedet")))
```

Although `(load "cedet")` should probably be `(require 'cedet)`, or you'll wind up reloading it every time.  (I'm not sure if CEDET has a `(provide 'cedet)`, so I didn't do it that way in my example.)

Note that putting advice on `require` will not do anything if semantic has already been loaded, so you may need to check `(featurep 'semantic)` first and load cedet.el immediately if necessary.

Comment: Hooking into require does work. I had to remove the apostrophe before CEDET-require. The problem is that even though eassist-list-methods loads, it has nothing to display. I have to revert the buffer so all the Semantic parsing stuff kicks in. That wasn't really the idea, though. Too complicated. I guess I'll just stick with loading CEDET when I start Emacs.  That doesn't happen very often anyway. Well, now I know more about defadvice ;).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all the CEDET stuff in your `load-path` something like:

```
(autoload 'eassist-list-methods "cedet" nil t)
```

in your `.emacs.d/init.el` (or other init file) should do the trick.

Comment: You don't normally use the ".el" extension with `autoload` or `load`, so I've taken the liberty of removing it.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks -- silly copy-n-paste from the 'load cedet.el' in the question... 8^)

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems if `eassist-list-methods` wasn't defined in cedet.el?

Comment: I already tried that. The problem is that I also have (autoload 'eassist-list-methods "eassist" nil t) in my .emacs and it doesn't work with two autoloads for the same function.

Comment: seth, for me, eassist is a separate library. I read on EmacsWiki that it's part of CEDET now. I haven't upgraded CEDET in a while because of other dependencies, though.

Comment: I don't think it's a requirement that `eassist-list-methods` be defun'd in 'cedet.el', but if loading `cedet.el' doesn't also load the file that defines that function, yeah, this isn't going to work. I don't use CEDET; I was assuming that since the eassist stuff came with CEDET, that loading it all up would do the trick.

Comment: Okay, @Eisen, how about if instead you make a file -- call it 'load-eassist-and-cedet.el' -- put `(load "cedet.el")` and `(load eassist.el)` in there, then have the autoload be `(autolad 'eassist-list-methods "load-eassist-and-cedet" nil t)`.

Yes, that's incredibly ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding you, but if not the answer is **`autoload`**: you want to load `eassist.el` only when you invoke one of its commands.  When it loads it will load `semantic` or CEDET or whatever it needs -- that's not your problem (it should be taken care of by the design of library `eassist.el`).

```
(autoload 'eassist-list-methods "eassist" nil t)
```